# Get map of address with python and OpenStreetMap

Tags: python, openstreetmap

I'd like to get a short map, where 2 places are marked. I don't need the route between them, only the location.

How can I get this short map using Python and OSM?
I found many wrappers, but I can't figure out how to work with addresses.

PS: Is there a possibility to work with a local database of one country? And how big will it be?

Answer (score 2):

How are your "places" described? By address? By location via lat,lon? And why do you need python?

If you just want to place two markers on a map you can use [Leaflet](http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/getting-started-with-leaflet/) or [OpenLayers](http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/getting-started-with-openlayers/). For transforming an address into a location (called *geocoding*) you can use [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim). And of course you can also work with a local OSM database with a [country extract](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts). The size will depend on the specific country as you can imagine.

For generating one large image you have to combine several [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles). This involves [figuring out which tiles will contain your places](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) after obtaining the coordinates for each place. Then, choose a reasonable zoom level depending on the distance between the two places. Afterwards you can download all tiles between them and put the images together. But keep the [tiles usage policy](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy) in mind or [render your own tiles](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/).

If this solution is too complicated you can take a look at other [rendering libraries](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering#Libraries).

Next time try to avoid asking multiple questions at once.

Comment: okay sorry I#ll try to do it better next time!
My places are described by address

Comment: What I need is one IMAGE showing this two locations. (I thought about a wrapper, so I mentioned pyhton)

Comment: *One* large image or a web-based [tile](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) viewer with an overlay on top containing the markers? I already explained how to get the tiles + marker thing.

Comment: To render it within a python application

Comment: You could have mentioned that in the original question.

Comment: yes sorry. I found something about how to get a web-based view, but nothing how to render it with the markers to an imagefile

Comment: I extended my answer but this isn't an easy task. Better try to stick with the web based view or use an already existing library.